# swagger split definition yaml - model structure not shown

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger 0.7.5 and trying to split swagger.yaml file into multiple. I used `swagger project create sample-api` command to create the project. The framework chosen was `express`. Execution of these commands created a nodejs project with ExpressJS setting and default `swagger.yaml` file. Since I am targeting a big application, I want to split yaml file across multiple. As per the documentation, I have started with externalizing response model to external file and here it is how it looks

**swagger.yaml**

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Hello Service
host: localhost:10010
basePath: /
... #skipping code for brevity
paths:
  /hello:
    x-swagger-router-controller: user
    get:
      description: Say hello
      operationId: hello
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: The name of the person to whom to say hello
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            # a pointer to a definition
            $ref: "#/definitions/HelloResponse"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
definitions:
  HelloResponse:
    $ref : models/response/hello_response.yaml
  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

**models/response/hello_response.yaml**

```
type: string
properties:
  message:
    type: string
```

After executing the command `swagger project start` at the root of the project directory, the service gets started and in browser the documentation is displayed. The problem is, the swagger doc doesn't display structure for externalized yaml file and shows following error message.

[image]

The directory structure for project looks like below

```
- api  
-- swagger
--- swagger.yaml
- config
-- config.yaml
- models
-- response
--- hello_response.yaml
- app.js
```

**Note**: I tried copying `models` directory at `swagger.yaml` level but that didn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, after trying out lot of options, I finally solved this problem by adding following line in `app.js`

```
app.use("/models", express.static("models"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing CuriousMind's response

```
const appRoot = require('app-root-path');

app.use("/paths", express.static(`${appRoot}/api/swagger/paths`));
app.use("/models", express.static(`${appRoot}/api/swagger/models`));
```

and after try : http://localhost:port/paths/yourfile.yaml